# How do i prevent recycled ListView items from showing old content?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm working on a ListView that uses a custom ResourceCursorAdapter to display a TextView and a CheckBox. The TextView and CheckBox get their state from the Cursor.  I've been having a few problems with it, the most recent being that when I scroll some of the rows have text from old  TextViews and some CheckBoxes are selected when they shouldn't be. I've added a log line to see what's going on and that's just confused me more.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context ctx, Cursor c) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();

holder.tv.setText(holder.tvText);           
holder.cb.setChecked(holder.checked);
Log.d(TAG, "in bindView, rowId:" + holder.rowId + " Scripture:" + holder.tvText);   
}
```

.

```
@Override
public View newView(Context ctx, Cursor c, ViewGroup vg){       

    View v = li.inflate(layout, vg, false);
    ViewHolder holder;

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(to[0]);
    holder.tvText = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(from[0]));
    holder.cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(to[1]);
    holder.rowId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(from[2]));
    holder.checked = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(from[1])).equals("n")) ?
            false : true;
    holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View rowView = ((View)v.getParent());
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();

            holder.checked = (holder.checked == false) ? true : false;

            smDb.setMemorized(holder.rowId);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
            Log.d(TAG, "check box clicked: " + holder.rowId);
        }});
    Log.d(TAG, "in newView, rowId:" + holder.rowId);
    v.setTag(holder);


    return v;       
}
```

.

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
    String tvText;
    CheckBox cb;
    boolean checked;
    Long rowId;
}
```

The Log output

```
in newView, rowId:26
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in newView, rowId:27
in bindView, rowId:27 Scripture:Matthew 6:24
in newView, rowId:28
in bindView, rowId:28 Scripture:Matthew 16:15-9
in newView, rowId:29
in bindView, rowId:29 Scripture:Matthew 25:40
in newView, rowId:30
in bindView, rowId:30 Scripture:Luke 24:36-9
in newView, rowId:31
in bindView, rowId:31 Scripture:John 3:5
in newView, rowId:32
in bindView, rowId:32 Scripture:John 7:17
in newView, rowId:33
in bindView, rowId:33 Scripture:John 10:16
in newView, rowId:34
in bindView, rowId:34 Scripture:John 14:15
in newView, rowId:26
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
in bindView, rowId:26 Scripture:Matthew 5:14-6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the view recycling that's causing your issue.

I'm not sure this is the smoothest way of handling it, but this is how I did it.  I made an array to hold my button state information and then used it in my getView method to make sure the state is maintained even when an element goes off-screen.

Example from one of my projects where I have a list adapter with buttons on each row that can have several states (text and color):

```
public class ButtonCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private Cursor c;                       // Passed in cursor
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    public static String[] atdState;       // String array to hold button state
    public static String[] atdRow;         // Matching string array to hold db rowId

    public ButtonCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                    String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            this.c = c;
            this.context = context;
            this.activity = (Activity) context;
            atdState = new String[c.getCount()];  // initialize button state array
            atdRow = new String[c.getCount()];    // initialize db rowId array
            c.moveToFirst();
            int i = 0;
            while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    if (c.getString(3) == null) {  // if state is null, set to " "
                            atdState[i] = " ";
                    } else {
                            atdState[i] = c.getString(3);  // set state to state saved in db
                    }
                    atdRow[i] = c.getString(0);     // set the rowId from the db
                    i++;
                    c.moveToNext();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null)
                    convertView = View.inflate(context,
                                    R.layout.listlayoutdoublebutton, null);
            final int pos = position;
            View row = convertView;
            c.moveToPosition(position);
            TextView first = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListItem1);
            TextView last = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListItem2);
            Button atdButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.attendbutton);
            first.setText(c.getString(1));
            last.setText(c.getString(2));
            atdButton.setText(atdState[position]);  // set the button state
            if (atdState[position].equals("P")) {   // colorize the button depending on state
                    atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00,
                                    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            } else if (atdState[position].equals("T")) {
                    atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFFFF00,
                                    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            } else if (atdState[position].equals("E")) {
                    atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF6600,
                                    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            } else if (atdState[position].equals("U")) {
                    atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,
                                    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            } else {
                    atdButton.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            }
            atdButton.setFocusable(true);
            atdButton.setClickable(true);

            atdButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                            Button atdButton = (Button) view
                                            .findViewById(R.id.attendbutton);
                            String test = atdButton.getText().toString();
                            if (test.equals(" ")) {
                                    atdButton.setText("P");
                                    atdState[pos] = "P";
                                    atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00,
                                                    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            } else if (test.equals("P")) {
                                    atdButton.setText("T");
                                    atdState[pos] = "T";
                                    atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFFFF00,
                                                    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            } else if (test.equals("T")) {
                                    atdButton.setText("E");
                                    atdState[pos] = "E";
                                    atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF6600,
                                                    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            } else if (test.equals("E")) {
                                    atdButton.setText("U");
                                    atdState[pos] = "U";
                                    atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,
                                                    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            } else if (test.equals("U")) {
                                    atdButton.setText("P");
                                    atdState[pos] = "P";
                                    atdButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00,
                                                    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            }
                    }
            });
            return (row);
    }
```

}

Where I use setText and colorize my button you would want to setChecked or some such, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've solved the problem with repeating items by throwing all of my ViewHeader code into the bindView method which is what I was doing before. Now I'm back to a previous problem where when I click a CheckBox it's state changes on screen and in the database but when I scroll it off the screen and bring it back it's back in its original state.  Is there a way to set the state when it's created AND when it's redrawn? (exiting the Activity and coming back shows the changes)

Comment: That's the code I showed in my answer.  Create an array to hold the state of the items and refer to in in your bindView.  If you look at my code you'll see I assign the button text and color based on my array rather than directly.  Keep the array updated as you make changes and every time it loads the view it will set the state properly.