# control when listView removes nonvisible views?

Tags: android, listview, universal-image-loader

I find listView recycles its views too fast.

When my listView scrolls, views falls off the screen gets removed right away.

Each cell(row) has image loaded using universal-image-loader.
Views which fell off the screen has to reload the image when they comes back into visible area. (it shows the stub image for short time period and loads the correct image).

I definately need to keep the view recycling behavior, but can I modify the list view's behavior so that user won't notice constant reloading of images?(maybe I keep 2-3 times of # of views in a cache than a regular list view would)

Comment: Show please your configuration (ImageLoaderConfiguration) and display options (DisplayImageOptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the code for ListView and friends is horribly complicated by the fact that it's designed to scroll unevenly-sized items without knowing the height ahead of time. That makes it brutally difficult to run with anything but the default behavior. In addition, most of the methods you'd need access to, to easily customize the behavior are hidden or private. It would be a massive job to try and roll your own (across multiple platforms, subtleties of scrolling, flinging, dragging, scrolling, keyboard focus &c).

The best solution is probably to maintain an image cache that fills in lazily around the view positions that are active. Not neccesarily easy. But way easier that trying to mess with ListView.

A very useful API for this is  ListView.setRecyclerListener(AbsListView.RecyclerListener listener), which gives you a hook to track which images are actively displayed.

Comment: Thanks for input. I enabled cache on universal-image-loader. But loading image back from cache is not fast enough so that I can notice it's reloading everytime when it goes out&come back into screen. Maybe am I not correctly using universal-image-loader's cache?

Comment: @Eugene, there is also a cache on your listview which can be enabled.

Comment: The real problem is you need to fill in a row or two in front of or behind the visible items. No amount of caching is going to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use a ScrollView instead of the list view. The ListView is designed to display a lot of data efficiently, that's why your off screen items are destroyed. In which concerns the scroll view, once loaded, you will be able to scroll up and down without recreating the off screen objects (because they ill not be destroyed).

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

EDIT:

If it is mandatory for you to use the listView, you cluld take a look here: [How do i prevent recycled ListView items from showing old content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158707/how-do-i-prevent-recycled-listview-items-from-showing-old-content)

There is a posibility to override the listView getView method and keep more items not to be destroyed that the number the listView is keeping.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. But I definitely need to keep the recycling behavior since I expect lots of data. I want to figure out a way to control how listview recycles or I need to add recycling behavior to scrollview.(I don't know which is easier)

Comment: I've glimpsed over it before posting the question. It looks like the problem there was to keep the `data` for cell not the cell itself.

Comment: Try to find then how to override the ScrollView in order to refresh some data on it.